# iOS10.3.1 - <Cordova/CDVViewController.h> file not found - After Upgrade

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ios10

I was running an ionic app successfully, but when i upgraded to iOS10.3.1 and Xcode 8.3.1 then whenever i create a new project and build it
i get the error

```
<Cordova/CDVViewController.h> file not found
```

How to fix this. How to downgrade to lower versions.

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
iOS : 4.3.1
```

Comment: This is not a PhoneGap Build question. Please amend your tags.

Comment: I am having the same issue, might have to rollback xcode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Xcode 8.3.2 this solved by running:

```
ionic resources
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios
```

src: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found/89548

Answer (score 1):

The other solution didn't work for me. Running this did:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-console
```

The cordova-plugin-console functionality has been moved to the core in cordova-ios 5.5.0, and including it is now a redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but only when Archiving. I researched a lot but none of the solutions worked. I did not want to remove the platform and add it again.
The only thing that worked for me is this:

1. Clean you project
2. **Build** your project
3. Archive your project. The Archive should now be successful.